# SQL Password not setting * not change password but not setting password

Tags: mysql, passwords

Having trouble setting the password on the command line for MYSQL. My original installation from homebrew  was successful and I was able to access the database by entering mysql.  However when I am setting up the new password it will not recognize it.  I know that I have been typing my new password and confirming my new password correctly so I don't think it an error like that.

Code:
Fareedahs-MacBook-Pro:~ fareedahjames$ mysqladmin password
New password: 
Confirm new password: 
mysqladmin: unable to change password; error: 'Can't find any matching row in the user table'

I even tried entering the password incorrectly just to test the error message so when the password i have typed match it is not setting the password
code:
     Fareedahs-MacBook-Pro:~ fareedahjames$ mysqladmin password
     New password: 
     Confirm new password: 
     mysqladmin: Passwords don't match

I read on another post about using

```
 SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'127.0.0.1' = password('cangetin');
```

but it did not work 
I tried running that in mysql and got 
     ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'

I am at a loss

Comment: did you run mysql as `mysql -u root` ?

Comment: I tried using mysql -u root and I got:ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) However I can just type mysql and I get into the data base

Comment: so now you can use it?

Comment: no I still cannot set my password

Comment: so currently you do not have any password, and you want to set a password, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't have the grant permission..
check the entries in your mysql.user table and paste here if possible.

Thanks

Comment: How do I check mysql.user table ?

Comment: you error shows ''@'localhost'...
it means you have to check :   show grants for ''@'localhost'
and paste here.

Comment: how do I check for grants @ localhost? what should I enter on the command line?

Comment: I get this error:   Fareedahs-MacBook-Pro:~ fareedahjames$ show grants for ''@'localhost'
-bash: show: command not found

Answer (score -1):

### Changing MySQL root user password using mysql command

This is an another method. MySQL stores username and passwords in user table inside MySQL database. You can directly update or change the password using the following method for user called root:

Login to mysql server, type the following command at shell prompt:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
```

Use mysql database (type command at mysql> prompt):

```
mysql> use mysql;
```

Change password for user root, enter:

```
mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("NEWPASSWORD") where User='root';
```

Finally, reload the privileges:

```
mysql> flush privileges;
mysql> quit
```

Comment: Fareedahs-MacBook-Pro:~ fareedahjames$ mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

Comment: try method 2 as mentioned above

Comment: when i try the 1st step in method 2 I get  mysql> $ mysql -u root -p 
    ->  that little arrow pops up and I am not in mysql> to type the next command

Comment: skip step 1; step 1 is used when u are not logged in yet in mysql

Comment: `mysql> ` - dont run this codes, just run what's after it.

Comment: this is what I get:                                                            mysql> use mysql
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'
mysql> use mysql;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'

Comment: /Users/fareedahjames/Desktop/Screen Shot 2014-05-15 at 10.43.21 PM.png

Comment: quit your current instance of mysql and start with `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: you have to login as root user first.

Comment: I am a beginner so this is all new to me.  I was trying to send a screen shot of my terminal so that it could make more sense

Comment: just hit enter without typing anything

Comment: this is what I get:  ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Fa

Comment: run this code on your mysql `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user` and post your results

Comment: and i think you have the same problem as http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,600754,600754

Comment: one question,  so when your in mysql are you in the shell because I get a -> when I enter SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user. then when I enter it just give more of the ->

Comment: you forgot to type `;` after pressing enter

Comment: I did that and I got ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table 'user'